# Showing a function space is infinite dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $C_\infty (\mathbb R) = \{ f \in C(\mathbb R) \mid \lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x) = 0 \}$ and Let $C_0(\mathbb R) = \{ f \in C(\mathbb R) \mid f \text{ has compact support} \}$.

I want to show that $C_\infty $ is infinite dimensional (I already showed it's a vector space).

> Please could someone read my work and tell me if it is correct?

Note that $C_0$ is a subspace of infinite dimension. To see this,
let $f_1, \dots, f_n \in C_0 (\mathbb R) \subseteq C_\infty$. Let $K$ be such that $f_i(x) = 0$ for $|x| > K$. Let $f(x) = f_1({x \over K})$. Then $f \in C_0$ is non-zero for $|x|> K$ and can therefore be not expressed as a linear combination of $f_i$. Hence $C_0$ has infinite dimension.

> Is there a better way to do this? Like for example, without using
>   $C_0$?

Comment: The notation $C_0$ is more commonly used for functions which merely decay at infinity. $C_c$ is used for compactly supported continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write down a countably infinite number of bump functions centered on integers with a 'width' of one.

Comment: Ok. Does it mean my proof is also correct?

Comment: Simon's approach is pretty much the same as yours philosophically.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yeah, I guess so. I just wanted someone to tell me that what I did was correct explicitly...

Comment: Upon re-reading my proof I believe to have found a mistake.

Comment: I think I fixed it. I updated my question with the fixed proof.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that if $0<a_1< a_2 < \dots < a_n,$ then the functions $e^{-a_1x^2}, \dots , e^{-a_nx^2}$ are linearly independent.